# PHP link doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, hyperlink

I am having an image hover on a php page and that image should link to a certain URL.

```
if(file_exists($actionsloaded)) 
    echo '<a href=\"index.php\"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/'.$image_on.'" onmouseover="this.src=\'/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/'.$image_off.'\';" onmouseout="this.src=\'/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/'.$image_on.'\';"/></a>';
else
```

Problem is, when I click the link it goes to `url.com/"index.php/"`

Any ideas what might be wrong with it?

Comment: Don't escape the quotes

Comment: You don't need to escape `href`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `\` on `href`. i have resolved and you can used this code

```
echo '<a href="index.php\"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/'.$image_on.'" onmouseover="this.src=\'/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/'.$image_off.'\';" onmouseout="this.src=\'/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/'.$image_on.'\';"/>asdf</a>'
```

if `$image_on=10;` and `$image_off =20;` then this code show on browser

```
<body><a href="index.php\"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/10" onmouseover="this.src='/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/20';" onmouseout="this.src='/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/10';">asdf</a></body>
```

Comment: There's no `/` in `href`, I think you mean `\ `. And you left the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You shuld remove all quote escape and see below updated code.

```
if(file_exists($actionsloaded)) 
    echo '<a href="index.php"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/'.$image_on.'" onmouseover="this.src='/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/'.$image_off.'';" onmouseout="this.src='/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/'.$image_on.'';"/></a>';
else
```